# Image responsiveness issue CSS

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I am using Owl Carousel for image slider . The issue is I want all of my images in a square shape containers (Single container for each image) 
I can resolve this issue with

**width:100%; height:auto**

But the problem occurs when I use different resolution of images. Each image can have different resolution but still I want all the images to be shown as
300x300 or 400x400 on big screens and responsive so after

Comment: can you post your html/css code of your slider? height:auto will just make it a height which responds to the ratio of the image, if your original image is not square , auto won't work. you have to force the size e.g: width:300 height:300.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think forcing the size is the best way to solve this, it depends on what you want to manipulate, is it the height or width?

```
#editedWidth {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

#editedHeight {
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
}
```

Link to [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVoaXm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't helped me actually the problem is . All I want is that image fits itself in the container . And container should be square so the image pixels adjusts as in square shape. I don't know weather there is any solution for that but i made it by using media query

It isn't about specific width or height. because picture can be of any width or any height

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size: cover` - http://codepen.io/bluminethemes/pen/Yqobgx

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be your image responsive then you should your image with square resolution because if you use rectangle type image then it will re-size according to original resolution